# Refreshing browser after PayPal PDT payment causes item to be bought twice

Tags: paypal, eclipse-pdt

I have implemented PayPal payments using PDT. I realize a combination of PDT and IPN is recommended, however for my purposes PDT is sufficient.

I am able to direct user to PayPal, collect payment and then conduct an action (updating account credits for the user in the database) when the user returns to my site. The URL shows an address like:

```
http://www.domain.com/process_pdt?tx=45138128VH922173V&st=Completed&amt=1.99&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=
```

So far so good. The problem I have is refreshing the browser with this URL causes the user's account to get credited again without redirecting the user to PayPal to collect payment a second time.

I have read that I should add the transaction id (tx in URL above) to the user table and check to ensure this tx id has not already been used. If it has, I should display an error message. Is this the only way to go about this, i.e. by storing each tx id in the user table and then checking for the id's existence each time the process_pdt URL above is called by the user (legitimately or fraudulently)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes: this is indeed the only way to go. As a simple sanity check you may want to do a redirect from the process page to a URL that does not include the `txn_id` (that way a casual refresh won't cause the problem, but if they use their back button it will still happen) but you must verify that the txn_id is only used once yourself.

Comment: Even better; use IPN instead. PDT will depend on the buyer returning to your site. Which is nice for a confirmation message, but absolutely not to be advised for any transactional changes (e.g. adding / removing credit). With IPN, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place (although it's still recommend to build a fool-proof IPN script that handles multiple POSTs gracefully.)